# How to write a TypeAdapter for multiple JSON objects with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have a JSON feed with multiple nested JSON objects. I have written my POJO classes and have looked on here for how to deserialize nested JSON objects to access the data I needed. However I am still receiving `NullPointerException`s on my nested JSON objects:

#### JSON feed example

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "relationships": {
                "dismissals": {
                    "meta": {
                        "count": {
                            "home": 0,
                            "away": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "data": []
                },
                "home": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "teams",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Pojo Mappings

Relationships:

```
public class Relationships implements Serializable

    @SerializedName("region")
    @Expose
    private Region region;
    @SerializedName("competition")
    @Expose
    private Competition competition;

getters and setters

}
```

Region:

```
public class Region implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data data;

}
```

Data

```
public class Data implements Serializable, Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

}
```

#### My `TypeAdapter`

```java
public class ItemTypeDataFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }}
```

#### Retrofit builder:

```java
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeDataFactory()) // This is the important line ;)
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
```

For example I want to get:

```java
getRelationships().getDissmissals().Meta().Count().Home();
```

When I run my app I get `NullPointerException` for that.

Is there something I need to add to my type adapter to deserialize the classes so I can get the data in multiple nested JSON objects? I have tried looking on here already and nothing has helped.

Comment: Why not just posting the POJO mappings? Also, `getRelationships().getDissmissals().Meta().Count().Home()` -- any invocation can cause NPE here. Unchaining it would help you to figure out which accessor causes the NPE.

Comment: Hi Lyubomyr-shaydariv, i didnt post mappings as would be alot of code in one page but can do now

Comment: Well, you're getting the NPE because something goes wrong with your mappings. It would really nice if you could post _short_ mappings: just properties that you have posted in the question (relationships, dismissals, meta, count and home) and just skip the rest keeping the essentials only -- they would be enough to spot the problematic property. At least it might shed some more light on why you need the type adapter there...

Comment: i have posted the mappings above, edited the post, not sure how much shorter it can get, as cut out unecessary getters and setters and just showing the mappings created.

Comment: There are still some missing classes: _one of them_ is `Competition`. Anyway, not to waste more time, just split your `getRelationships().getDissmissals().Meta().Count().Home()` into separate statements (like `relations = getRelations(); dismissals = relations.getDismissals`) -- you'll spot the problematic mapping because chained methods are hard to debug in that manner.

Answer (score -2):

Some times it's difficult to generate the POJO class for a JSON response.
You can generate your POJO easily here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: that what i used and choose options to make it serialiazble but is not working getting data from class as point at a null